# Response status code was unacceptable: 403 for iPad only

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Im having a weird bug with the parse server and retrieving files. 
It seems to only be effecting the simulator with iPad Air, Air2, Pro 9.7inch

The iPhone and 12.9inch ipad work as expected, they display the images and videos. But the others above produce the error:

> Response status code was unacceptable: 403

And don't display the images
Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out to be simple problem.
I forgot i had migrated my database, and the images and videos where pointing to the older database. 
It seemed that some of the simulators where using cached files and thats why they were working and others not.